# UrlGenerationError in self-referenced model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a self-referential Post model for nested conversations. The parent post renders child posts with partials _post and _form. Every post has typical crud actions for "reply", "edit", and "delete".

**Problem**: The edit action of child replies throw a "UrlGenerationError Missing Required Keys [:id]" error, even though the ID parameter is present in the request. Yet the delete action works fine, and all actions work fine in the parent Post, too.

[image: screenshot of a parent post and two nested child posts]

post.rb:

```
has_many :child_posts, class_name: "Post", foreign_key: "parent_post_id"
belongs_to :parent_post, class_name: "Post", optional: true
```

routes.rb:

```
resources :posts
```

_post.html.erb:

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post.id), ... %>
```

_form.html.erb: (The error occurs at the `<%= form_for post do |f| %>` tag.)

```
<% puts params.inspect # ->  <ActionController::Parameters {"controller"=>"posts", "action"=>"edit", "id"=>"123"} permitted: false> %> 
<%= form_for post do |f| %>
...
```

Happy to show more--this just seems the most relevant. Thoughts?

Comment: The incoming parameters and the form URL have nothing to do with each other. You're looking at the problem wrong. The real issue is why the route helper is failing. What does inspecting `post` tell you? Are you overriding `to_param` in your model. What does `polymorphic_url(post)` tell you?

Comment: I'm guessing the most likely cause is just a typographic error though. Perhaps you should be using the instance variable `@post` and not  the local variable `post`.

Comment: polymorphic_url(post) reveals the same error, but that prompted me to realize this is due to a conflict I introduced with the has_permalink gem, by trying to support both permalinks (for original posts) and id numbers (for replies). I should think of a better solution, obviously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by a conflict I introduced with the has_permalink gem. (The gem works as intended)